# How one aligns structure fields in Squeak FFI

Tags: smalltalk, ffi, squeak

If I define a structure like this `struct foo {char x; float y ; char z; double t};` the alignment can be platform dependent, but I'd expect offset 0,4,8,16 for the members x,y,z,t respectively on most architectures/compilers.

If I define corresponding structure in Squeak

```
ExternalStructure subclass: #Foo 
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'FFI-Tests'.
```

and define the fields naively with

```
Foo class>fields
    ^#(
        (x 'char')
        (y 'float')
        (z 'char')
        (t 'double') )
```

then generate the accessors with `Foo defineFields`, I get those packed offsets:

```
Foo>>x
    ^handle unsignedCharAt: 1

Foo>>y
    ^handle floatAt: 2

Foo>>z
    ^handle unsignedCharAt: 6

Foo>>t
    ^handle doubleAt: 7
```

That is field offsets of 0,1,5,6 respectively.

How am I supposed to obtain a platform compatible alignment?

- insert padding fields?
- force the previous field size?
- forget about the auto-generated thing and code all the access methods by myself?

Answer (score 2):

If I force the size as the 3rd element of some of the fields spec, then I can obtain desired offsets.

```
Foo class>>fields
    ^#(
        (x  'char'  4)
        (y  'float' )
        (z  'char'  8)
        (t  'double')
    )
```

I would have preferred a way to specify alignment of current field rather than forcing the size of previous field, but well, maybe someone will find a better solution.

Note that it is a size in bytes. If I replace char with short, then I must keep the same byte-size spec in 3rd column if I want to obtain the same offsets 0,4,8,16.

```
Foo class>>fields
    ^#(
        (x  'short'  4)
        (y  'float' )
        (z  'short'  8)
        (t  'double')
    )
```

Comment: There is usually a rule that says that a field of, say, length 4 like `y 'float'` in your example must be aligned to 4, etc. Therefore there might be some automatic alignment, or at least some attempt of it.

Comment: If alignment may be platform-specific but still specific to Squeak FFI's external types (i.e. atomic type or struct type), then it makes sense to store that information in `ExternalType` to be updated in image startup if a platform change is detected. What is the scope and context for field alignment computation? I would rather not have to write it down in `#fields`...

Comment: In the mean time, OS/arch specific alignment has been programmed in Squeak FFI. This answer did document the existing solution at time of writing, but the question will deserve an updated anwer once the API is settled.